# unable to save image in widget apostrope

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nunjucks, apostrophe-cms

I don't have much knowledge about apostrophe but I tried to create a custom widget. I want three fields in my widget:

1. heading (string)
2. description (string)
3. a image

I haven't found a way to add an image in the widget as field.

Now, I added a singleton inside the widget, it works fine. but when add an image it displays on the page but when i reload the page the image is gone.

My `widget.html` code

```html
<div class="md-jumbotron">

<div class="md-grid">
    <h1>{{ data.widget.heading }}</h1>
    <h6>{{ data.widget.desc }}</h6>

    <div class="img">
        {{ apos.singleton(data.page, 'jumbotroPic', 'apostrophe-images', {
            limit: 1,
            size: 'full'

        }) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I got the following on console

```html
$ node app.js

WARNING: No session secret provided, please set the `secret` property of the 
`session` property of the apostrophe-express module in app.js
WARNING: widget type text exists in content but is not configured
WARNING: widget type text exists in content but is not configured
I see no data/address file, defaulting to address 0.0.0.0
I see no data/port file, defaulting to port 3000
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000
WARNING: widget type text exists in content but is not configured
WARNING: widget type text exists in content but is not configured
WARNING: widget type text exists in content but is not configured
WARNING: widget type text exists in content but is not configured
```

My javascript code for the widget is:

```html
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Jumbotron',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'heading',
      type: 'string',
      label: 'Heading',
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: 'desc',
      type: 'string',
      label: 'Description',
      required: true
    }
  ],
  construct: function(self, options) {
    var superPushAssets = self.pushAssets;
    self.pushAssets = function() {
      superPushAssets();
      self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'jumbotron', { when: 'always' });
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an image widget to your widget's schema like this

```
 {
  name: 'image',
  label: 'Jumbo Image',
  type: 'singleton',
  widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
  options: {
    limit: 1,
  }
}
```

Just stick it in `addFields` array.

Thanks for trying out Apostrophe!

Answer (score 0):

Ok here I found the whole solution:

here is my widget schema:

```js
 module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Jumbotron',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'heading',
      type: 'string',
      label: 'Heading',
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: 'desc',
      type: 'string',
      label: 'Description',
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: 'image',
      label: 'Jumbo Image',
      type: 'singleton',
      widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
      options: {
        limit: 1,
      }
    }
  ],
  construct: function(self, options) {
    var superPushAssets = self.pushAssets;
    self.pushAssets = function() {
      superPushAssets();
      self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'jumbotron', { when: 'always' });
    };
  }
};
```

here is my widget html code

```html
<div class="md-jumbotron">

    <div class="md-grid">
        <h1>
        {{ data.widget.heading }}
        </h1>
        <h6>
        {{ data.widget.desc }}
        </h6>

        <div class="img">
            {{
                apos.singleton(
                    data.widget,
                    'image',
                    'apostrophe-images',
                    {
                        edit: false
                    }
                )
            }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

taken html code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44451677/edit)